# Cancel MongoDB transaction programmatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using MongoDB transactions as the following example shows and I am wondering if there is a way to cancel the updating transaction programmatically in case the following step fails.

```
  const session = client.startSession();

  try {
    await session.withTransaction(async () => {

      await coll1.insertOne({ abc: 1 }, { session });
      await coll2.insertOne({ xyz: 999 }, { session });
    }, transactionOptions);

      // Now that the DB is updated, I'll try to use a service
      const result = paymentProcessor.chargeCard(billingDetails, 200);
      if(result.error) **cancelTransactionAndRestoreEvery();**

  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
    await client.close();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use session.abortTransaction() to abort a transaction so everything that happened already in the transaction will be rolled back.

See http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/ClientSession.html#abortTransaction for the official docs.

See https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/quick-start-nodejs--mongodb--how-to-implement-transactions for example code that uses abortTransaction().

Answer (score 0):

In other way first you can connect session using

`const session = await connection.startSession();`
in this connections will be either using mongoose or mongoDb client

then you have to start the transaction

```
  try {
    await session.startTransaction();

      await coll1.insertOne({ abc: 1 }, { session }); 

      await coll2.insertOne({ xyz: 999 }, { session });

      // Now that the DB is updated, I'll try to use a service
      const result = paymentProcessor.chargeCard(billingDetails, 200);
      if(result.error) {
         await session.abortTransaction(); // this will not update changes to db
      }

    await session.commitTransaction(); // if every thing goes well comit your changes 
  }catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error)
        await session.abortTransaction();
  } finally {
    await session.endSession();
  }
```